# How to remove count of specific byte in array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to remove bytes from an array, I don't want to remove all bytes `0x6f` I just want to remove two only of them. This is my code:

```
string msg = "gooooooal";
byte[] oldArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(msg);
byte[] newArray = oldArray.Where(b => b != 0x6f).ToArray();
```

Comment: But Which two??

Comment: Can I remove any two I need? It will be very good.

Comment: Yes but you will have to define any. Like first two, last two or random two? And what if there are more than two same exists in array?

Comment: Actually, I want to adjust the length not important witch two because the count will not be fixed!

Comment: But may I know why do you want to this?

Comment: Yes, I will copy a string contains more than 14 bytes from file to another, so I want to adjust length to be 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first find the position and then remove them

```
 byte[] oldArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(msg);

int howManyToRemove = 2; //How many items to remove
var positions = new List<int>();
int lastPos = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < howManyToRemove; i++)
{
    var position = Array.IndexOf(oldArray, (byte)0x6f,lastPos+1);
    if (position == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    lastPos=position;
    positions.Add(position);
}

byte[] newArray = oldArray.Where((val, idx) => !positions.Contains(idx)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem then if want to delete two occurrences of the letter o from your string because the `0x6f` ASCII value is 111 which is the letter `o`.

and for that, you are making the solution very complex.

if can simply do like this.

```
string s = "gooooooal";
string output = removeChar(s, 'o'); //output will be gooool

static string removeChar(string s,
                char ch)
{

    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {

        // If ch is found
        if (s[i] == ch && count > 0)
        {
            s = s.Substring(0, i) +
                s.Substring(i + 1);
            count--;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```